# PHP Obtain client location

Tags: php, location, trace

I'd like to know how to obtain the location of a client. I know this is possible by simply tracing the IP, but this isn't very accurate. I noticed http://www.kickstarter.com/ was able to get my exact location. I tried it in 2 different browsers, cleared my cookies and all, and it was still able to get my location. It didn't ask me to allow the page to get my address. How is this done?

To the people that are suggesting me to use geo-ip, please read the actual question. If you trace my ip you get a COMPLETELY different location which is about 100km off of my actual location, whily Kickstarter knows my EXACT location.

Comment: Maybe KickStarter is using Flash cookies, or a unique identifier in the URL? Exact location finding is impossible unless you allow it in some way. Or do you have location services turned on? What system are you using? If it is a mobile device, perhaps it is using cell tower tracking?

Comment: Or maybe Kickstarter is using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, and you happen to have a clean, non proxy IP? Try going to kickstarter through a proxy and see what happens

Comment: firefox,chrome,safari all expose via javascript the user location if requested (in firefox for example you will get a popup saying site xxx is requesting your location information) usually only used on phones/mobile devices with location information in it so it could just be that its pulling it from geoip as linked below

Comment: halfer I am running on Windows XP, and this was the first time I have visited this site. I have never allowed it to view my location, which is why i'm so stunned.

Answer (score 0):

You can GEOIP the user, here is the [PHP Manual on GEOIP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)

Answer (score 0):

Those websites base your location on your IP address, for instance using [Geo IP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php). This is not always a reliable feature, most of the time they show me a wrong location.

There are other solutions as well, such as browser geolocation, but this is not supported by older browsers (see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=geolocation) for browser support). Browsers who do support it, should ask for permission.

See [this website](http://mylocation.org/) for some examples of geolocation methods.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to allow a page to get your IP address. The server ALWAYS knows the IP address it needs to talk to. If you don't use a proxy, it will know the direct address your request comes from.